# using api.getoptions to retrieve all options for a field (even disabled)

Tags: api

According to the documentation (https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Pseudoconstant+(option+list)+Reference) I should be able to pass a context to an api.getoptions call in order retrieve both enabled and disabled options for a field. However, it doesn't seem to be working. In fact, swapping out different contexts has no apparent effect on what is returned by the api call. Am I missing something?

Sample code:

```
$opts = civicrm_api3('contribution', 'getoptions', array(
  'field' => "custom_5",
  'context' => 'get'
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you found a bug. Here is a fix:

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9540

Could you please review it and leave feedback on github to speed along the merge process?